# How to programmatically clear android logcat log from application

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

Is there a way to clear android logcat from the application itself.

I'm able to read logcat within the app using;

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d -v long");

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```

but using

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c");
```

and the re-reading with the above read method it's not possible to clear the log. It's just getting the same log again.

This however works within android emulator but not in actual device.

Comment: "I'm able to read logcat within the app" -- only for messages coming from your own process, unless you are a system app that holds the `READ_LOGS` permission.

Comment: OK, so need to clear and then also provide filtering... Thanks.

Comment: Actually it doesn't seem to clear even own logs (those that app writes e.g. with Log.d itself).

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: @Nanoc the app is showing log for on-the-field debugging purposes and there's lot of logs e.g. from earlier app runs (this is wanted) but when a specific error is encountered it's nicer to clear logs and then reproduce the issue from clean-slate log.

Comment: But you dont need to clean the logcat itself, just clean the list that shows it then load only new messages right?

Comment: Yeah, thats alternative to this but requires a bit more logic.